# Cannot Prevent Async on GraphQL Mutation and Recoil State updating process

Tags: react-native, asynchronous, async-await, graphql, recoiljs

I am working on a Chat Room portion of a larger React Native app and am facing issues with the updating of the page after a text has been sent. Currently, when the user compiles a text in a `TextInput` and hits the send button, it triggers a mutation that is supposed to add a `message` object to the `chatroom` model, which is linked to all of the `users` that are currently in the chatroom. It is then supposed to take the result from this mutation, which is the updated `chatroom` connected to all the `users` (the current user included obviously) and render its contents. It is intended to rerender the page after the `activeThread` atom is updated, since the page used the contents of `activeThread` to render everything on the page, new messages included. However, this occurs asyncronously and it tries to render a promise.... which you can't do. I've tried everything I'm capable of, using `then`s and `awaits` everywhere I could but JavaScript's giving me the middle finger pretty hard on this one. My code is below...

```
const handleSendMessage = async () => {
        console.log(activeThread.id)
        if (newMessage.length > 0){
             return sendMessage({
                variables: {
                    chatroomId: activeThread.id,
                    content: newMessage
                }
            }).then( async (newMessageThread) => {
                await setUpdating(true)
                await setNewMessage("")
                await setKeyboardVisible(false);
                await setActiveThread(newMessageThread)
            }).then( async() => {
                await console.log(activeThread)
                await setUpdating(false)
            })
        }
        else{
        }
    }
```

`setUpdating` is part of a useState. This is defaulted to `false` and when `true` the main page is not set to render. It is intended as a guard against attempting to render the promise. Didn't work, obviously

`setNewMessage` is defaulted to `""` and is responsible for keeping track of the text the user has entered into the `TextInput`. Pretty irrelevant here.

`setKeyBoardVisible` is pretty self explanatory and also not necessary

`setActiveThread` is the heavy lifter here. Pretty much all of the contents rendered are going to be pulling data from `activeThread`, which is, again; a recoil state. For example, everything below looks essentially something like

```
<View>
    <Text> {activeThread.someMethodOrValue} </Text>
</View>
```

I can only assume this has something to do with the async-ing. I have a `console.log(error)` statement in my backend GraphQL mutation resolver that would catch any errors there, and it's not triggering anything. The error I get everytime is the following...

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'activeThread.chatroomName.split')

This error is located at:
    in MessageThread (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by SceneView)
    in {/* keeps going down the stack you get the idea */}

[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'activeThread.chatroomName.split')]
at Pages/CommunicationPage/MessageThread.js:210:37 in MessageThread
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

While the code I had still looks like it should work to me, we all know how finnicky code can be sometimes. What ended up working was separating the `handleSendMessage` function and the mutation, creating a whole new function for the mutation.

My new code looks like this...

```js
const handleSendMessage = () => {
        if (newMessage.length > 0){
             handleMutation().then( (resolved) => { // This line fixed all the promise issues
                setNewMessage("") // clears current message input
                let newActiveThread = resolved.data.driverSendMessage.chatroom // creates new thread JSON from mutation data
                console.log(newActiveThread) // testing out a different bug now lolllll
                setActiveThread(newActiveThread) // Sets current thread to match the new one

                // changes the entire user state, leaving all over threads untouched but updating the current one
                let updatedThreads = [newActiveThread]
                user.chatrooms.forEach( (chat) => {
                    if (chat.id == newActiveThread.id){
                        console.log("Skipping " + newActiveThread.chatroomName)
                    }
                    else {
                        updatedThreads.push(chat)
                    }
                })

                // changes the main recoil state
                setUser({...user, chatrooms: updatedThreads})
            })
        }
        else{
            // Throw Error Handling for no input or just do nothing, we'll see
        }
    }

    const handleMutation = async () => {
        return sendMessage({
            variables: {
                chatroomId: activeThread.id,
                content: newMessage
            }
        })
    }
```